# How to create the shims for the sealed classes, and where can I find the `fakes`-format description?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes, stubbing

I need to generate the shims through *Microsoft Fakes Platform* for three sealed classes of external managed assembly. I wrote this:

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
  <Assembly Name="acmgd" Version="17.2.0.0"/>
  <StubGeneration>
    <Clear/>
  </StubGeneration>
  <ShimGeneration>
    <Clear />
    <Add FullName=
         "Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application"/>
    <Add FullName=
         "Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.DocumentCollection"/>
    <Add FullName=
         "Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Document"/>
  </ShimGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

The each of these classes is sealed. The *Microsoft Fakes Platform* doesn't create the shim for `Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application` (the `ShimApplication` class is not exist in the result):

> The type or namespace name `ShimApplication` does not exist in the
>   namespace `Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Fakes` (are you
>   missing an assembly reference?)

I haven't this problem for other two types. How can I fix it?

Also I have a question about the `fakes`-file structure. I can't find info about the `ShimGeneration` element. In the MSDN samples I see the `StubGeneration` element using only. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708916.aspx#BKMK_Shim_type_and_stub_type_naming_conventions):

> **Stubbing concrete classes and virtual methods**
>
> By default, stub types are generated for all non-sealed classes. It is
>   possible to restrict the stub types to abstract classes through the
>   .fakes configuration file:
>
> ```
> <Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
>   <Assembly Name="mscorlib" />
>   <!-- user code -->
>   <StubGeneration>
>     <Types>
>       <Clear />
>       <Add AbstractClasses="true"/>
>     </Types>
>   </StubGeneration>
>   <!-- /user code -->
> </Fakes>
> ```

But in real life the XSD schema doesn't define the `Types` and the `Add` hasn't `AbstractClasses` attribute...

Where can I find actual and detailed info about the `fakes`-format?

Comment: can't you just right-click the reference and generate fakes assembly?

Comment: @Crowcoder, why you think I made it through any other way? Of course I did it through the *Add Fakes Assembly* context menu item. I didn't ask how to generate fake. I asked about *configuring* of this process.

Comment: @Crowcoder, Sorry for my bad English. Perhaps I not clear described my problem.

Comment: Have you tried just doing a rebuild?  Sometimes the Fakes .dll needs to be regenerated (which is not always as predictable as it should be).  I'd try it myself but just have the AcDbMgd .dll.